# How to delete old mysql users from database

Tags: mysql, database, delete-row

I want to know how to delete old users from my MySQL database. For example check if they were unactive for about 30 days. I tried to do it in Java, but it just freezes.

Comment: What was your approach when you tried to delete users in Java?

Comment: '        for (DataUser user : getAllUsers()) {
            long delay = System.currentTimeMillis() - user.getLastJoined();
            if ((delay / 1000) > 86400 * 30) {
             user.delete();
            }
        }'

Comment: So this is using what? Hibernate? JPA? Something else?

Comment: I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest doing that from `mysql` side, go into workbench/console/whatever you are using and delete the users there, it's gonna be a simple query:

`DELETE FROM users WHERE dateJoined < yourDate`

If you want to do that in Java you will need to use JDBC, check here [JDBC tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/). If you want to do that only once then I really suggest using console, JDBC is a lot of boilerplate code and if you are not doing anything else with a database then there is no point, and I guess you are just doing all this to learn, not in production or anything.

Comment: How to subtract system current time from last joined time and check if it's longer than 30 days for example?

Comment: `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)` is current date - 30 days, then you need to check if user date is bigger than that, you can just do that with `>`

Comment: DELETE FROM users WHERE lastJoined > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
Like that? It didn't delete any of the users.

Comment: lastJoined is date when user joined, so it needs to be smaller than date_sub, and are you sure your field in users table is called lastJoined and it's a date field, not a varchar or something else?

Comment: It contains date in milliseconds.

Comment: Hm, try that: `DELETE FROM users WHERE lastJoined < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))*1000`

Comment: Thanks, it works. How to delete users that has same value in lastJoined table as in firstJoined? Something like that? DELETE FROM users WHERE lastJoined = firstJoined

Comment: Ye, something like that :) But they have to be identicial, even 1 milisecond difference and they are not the same.